# Meteor Collection not updating

Tags: javascript, mongodb, collections, meteor, meteorite

Pretty new to Meteor and I've been running into errors updating my mongoDB meteor collections ever since removing autopublish. Maybe I'm missing something very crucial about publishing now, but just typing into the console:

```
NVC.Users.insert({name:'bob'})
--> "MTi5ePEyHyKXZFWjL"
NVC.Users.find().fetch()
--> []
```

throws me off since before removing autopublish I could have sworn that this worked. Could somebody please explain what I'm missing, as I've also tried:

```
// Client
if Meteor.isClient
  Deps.autorun ->
    Meteor.subscribe 'rooms'


// Server
if Meteor.isServer
  Meteor.startup ->
    Meteor.publish 'rooms' , ->
      return Rooms.find()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put your subscribe in a `Deps.autorun`:

```
if Meteor.isClient
  Meteor.subscribe 'rooms'
```

Use Deps.autorun if you would like to change the subscription by passing it a variable via `Session`, but in the use case above you do not need it.

Deps.autorun runs every time a reactive dependency in it changes. But there aren't any so it doesn't run and makes no subscription to rooms

Comment: So I would use Deps if there was some property within the publish handler that changed, for example like counting the number of posts?

Comment: Not really, you would use it if you want to run some javascript when a `Session` changes, e.g changing the subscription by changing the room being subscribed to for the messages collection you might use. There's an example on how to do it on the meteor docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe where the room is set to `Session.get('current-room')`